# Atom command doesn't run atom

Tags: linux, atom-editor

So I've just installed Zorin on a computer to figure out how to use a Linux machine and I'm installing all of my favorite software that I got to use when I worked in Windows, and so far Anaconda, Spyder, and some other softwares have worked well.  I just followed the instructions to install the Atom text editor and didn't receive any error messages.  However, when I navigate to the folder where it installed and type `atom` in the terminal it tells me the command is not recognized.  In that folder when I type `dir` I see several files and `atom` is among them.

I tried googling this issue and found one person working from a Mac encountering the same issue, and was instructed to manually include a certain file in `usr/local/bin`, the suggestion seeming to be that this is where the OS looks for command names.  However, I looked in this location on my machine and the folder is entirely empty.  So I'm wondering if Linux is different and my command links are stored somewhere else.

In short, how do I run Atom now that I've downloaded it?

Comment: Try `./atom`. You probably don't have `.` in your `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH` to see where your shell is looking for executable files.

Comment: @yellowantphil That did the trick, thanks!  Should I have `.` in my `$PATH`, and if so, what should I search to find out how to do this?

Comment: You could if you want to, but it's a (slight) security risk. Is your shell `bash`? In that case, you could edit your path in `~/.bash_profile`. `PATH=.:$PATH` would add `.`. I don't especially recommend it, but the world wouldn't end if you felt like doing that. As for what to search, maybe search the bash man page for `PATH`. The "COMMAND EXECUTION" section might be informative, although it's fairly dry.

Comment: @yellowantphil I appreciate all your help. :)

Comment: Also, the "INVOCATION" section says what files `bash` reads when it starts up.

Comment: Actually, `PATH=$PATH:.` would probably be better. That puts `.` at the end of the search path, so you're less likely to overwrite commands unexpectedly, like if you have an executable file named `ls` in your current directory for some weird reason.

Comment: If you install Atom using your OS package manager then you can run it with the `atom` command from anywhere (there is more going on behind the scenes than that, but take it at face value for now if you are a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

atomSetup.exe should add the PATH variables, but if you run the installer just after downloading, the setup does not get the administrator right to install atom correctly, i have manually added path variables, but it didnt work, so i uninstalled atom completely then reinstalled,  right click on the atomSetup.exe >**Run as administartor**, wait to complete the setup. after installation atom command will work properly.